# Destroying Laravel session variable with plain php

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a session with Laravel:

```
Session::put('cart', $cart);
```

How can I destroy it with php like `session_destroy();`? Outside of Laravel directory.

Comment: have you configured it to store sessions in another directory?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: It's not straightforward. It depends on the session driver you used with Laravel (file, cookie, database, apc, memcached, redis, array). Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/15567365/4268599. It's old but still hold a clue to what you need